# Determine the method that has been used for numerical solution of elliptical PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am using the following script to solve a system of PDEs:

```
 t = ArcTan[x, y] + \[Pi];
 nx = Cos[t/2] ; 
 ny = Sin [t/2]  ;
 f = (Tanh[  2 ( x^2 + y^2 - 3 )] + 1)/2 ;
 V = -0.23;
 L = 40;
 \[Tau] = 66;
 V0 = 1;
 Dc = 4;
 eq1 = Dc \!\(
 \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(c[x, y]\)\) -  
    V  D[c[x, y], x] - V0 (D[nx w[x, y], x] + D[ny w[x, y], y] );
 eq2 = Dc \!\(
 \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(w[x, y]\)\) -  
    V  D[w[x, y], x] - V0 (D[nx c[x, y], x] + D[ny c[x, y], y]) - 
    2 w[x, y] /(f  \[Tau] ) ;
 {sc, sw} = 
   NDSolveValue[ {eq1 == 
      NeumannValue[ 0,  y == 0  || x == L   || x == -L  ], 
     DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == 1, y == L  ], 
     eq2 == NeumannValue[ 0, 
       y == 0  && x < 0 || x == L  || x == -L  ], 
     DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, y == L ],  
     DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, y == 0  && x   >= 0] }, {c, 
     w}, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-L, 0}, {L, L}]];
```

And it works well. Since I didn't specify any method or any other parameters in the `NDSolveValue` function, it chose everything automatically. Is it possible to extract the parameters (e.g. method, space-step, etc.) that has been used?

Cheers,
Mikhail